# String concatenation with spaces

Tags: string, matlab, concatenation

I would like to concatenate strings. I tried using `strcat`:

```
x = 5;
m = strcat('is', num2str(x))
```

but this function removes trailing white-space characters from each string. Is there another MATLAB function to perform string concatenation which maintains trailing white-space?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `horzcat` instead of `strcat`:

```
>> strcat('one ','two')
ans =
onetwo
>> horzcat('one ','two')
ans =
one two
```

Alternatively, if you're going to be substituting numbers into strings, it might be better to use `sprintf`:

```
>> x = 5;
>> sprintf('is %d',x)
ans =
is 5
```

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
strcat({' is '},{num2str(5)})
```

that gives

```
' is 5'
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the final example on the [`strcat` documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/strcat.html): try using horizontal array concatination instead of `strcat`:

```
m = ['is ', num2str(x)]
```

Also, have a look at [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) for more information on string formatting (leading/trailing spaces etc.).

Answer (score 2):

How about using [`strjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html) ?

```
x = 5;
m ={'is', num2str(x)};
strjoin(m, ' ')
```

Answer (score -2):

What spaces does this not take into account ?  Only the spaces you haven't mentioned !  Did you mean:

```
m = strcat( ' is ',num2str(x) )
```

perhaps ?

Matlab isn't going to guess (a) that you want spaces or (b) where to put the spaces it guesses you want.

Comment: that space you put there, will be trimmed off if you use strcat